# Serializable in Java - JGraphT's Pair class - Should the type of instance members also implement Serializable?

Tags: java, serializable, jgrapht

From [here](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-core/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/alg/util/Pair.java), JGraphT's `Pair` class is `Serializable`. But the instance members this class contains (`first` and `second`) are not forced to be `Serializable`.

This is how the current implementation looks like:

```java
public class Pair<A, B>
    implements
    Serializable
```

I think it should be something like:

```java
public class Pair<A extends Serializable, B extends Serializable>
    implements
    Serializable
```

Am I missing something? If not, then why is it not done by JGraphT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `Serializable` is only relevant during runtime.

If you want to use a pair with non-serializable elements it will work, except serialization will fail if it is attempted. However if both elements are `Serializable` then they will serialize regardless of the generic bounds.

- `Pair<A extends Serializable, B extends Serializable> implements Serializable` => Always serializable, but unable to be used for non-serializable `A`/`B`
- `Pair<A, B> implements Serializable` => Serializable if `A` and `B` happen to be `Serializable` during runtime, but no guarantees for any given `Pair`.
- `Pair<A, B>` / `Pair<A extends Serializable, B extends Serializable>` => Would never be serializable regardless of type parameters since the container itself is not `Serializable`.

Comment: Even if you want an always serialisable `Pair` the *static* types of `A` and `B` shouldn't be forced to be `Serializable`. (You could add a runtime check, but that would be very odd.)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline "even if we want `Pair` to be always serializable, then `A` and `B` shouldn't be forece to be `Serializable`" - Why? We are saying that `Pair` is `Serializable` - then shouldn't we force that `A` and `B` should also be `Serializable`?

Comment: Only if the class itself is meant to be ALWAYS serializable, by marking it as serializable without specifying the contents it supports serialization if the contents do. In all other cases it works as if the class is not serializable.

Comment: @LavishKothari Consider `List` for instance. The isn't `Serializable` because not all `List`s are `Serializable`, but you wouldn't want to prohibit `A` or `B` being some kind of `List`.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Thanks for the clear example. It helped me a lot in understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on the usage of `Serializable`. If this is used inside the Framework to serialize a `Pair` and crash otherwise, then you're right.

If this is not an absolute requirement and it is only Serializeable for the implementors, it is their responsibility to ensure that.

For example, the `java.util.ArrayList` also implements `Serializable`, although it doesn't demand it's members to be serializable. Serializing an `ArrayList` will fail if they are not.

Answer (score -1):

If A & B will be fields of your class, so they should be.

example of ArrayList and not Serializable content:

TestClass:

```
public class NonSerialClass {

    private int i;

    public NonSerialClass(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "NonSerialClass{" +
                "i=" + i +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Runner class:

```
        List<NonSerialClass> nonSerialClasses= new ArrayList<>();

        nonSerialClasses.add(new NonSerialClass(1));

        nonSerialClasses.add(new NonSerialClass(2));

        System.out.println("Before "+nonSerialClasses);


        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

        oos.writeObject(nonSerialClasses);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();


        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
        List ts = (List) oin.readObject();
        System.out.println("After "+ts);
```

And result will be:

```
Before [NonSerialClass{i=1}, NonSerialClass{i=2}]
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: ru.NonSerialClass
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
```

Comment: Please explain why

Comment: because if field exists and it is not transient, it must be seriliazible to serialize whole object

Comment: An `ArrayList` is also serializable, although its members dont have to be

Comment: It cannot be serialized (and I didn't say it would be), but like an ArrayList, you can use a Pair without serializing it.